# JSONRequest.post not functioning

Tags: javascript, json, http-post

I am developing a web page and the purpose is to perform an http POST from form input elements, in JSON format. While the JSON element to be sent is formed properly, the request is never performed. Here is the code I have been using.
**Form**

```
<form id="input" action="javascript:snifForm()" >



                   User ID:
                   <input type="text" name="userId" id="userId" required>
                   Name:
                   <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required>


        <div class="form-submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit" color="#ffffff" >       </div></p>
        </form>
```

**Javascript** (JSON.js, JSONRequest.js and JSONRequestError.js are imported)

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
       var requestNumber;
       function snifForm()
       {
           var a1=document.getElementById("userId").value;
           var a2=document.getElementById("name").value;


           var toSend= {interactions: {id_user:a1, id_name:a2}};

           var jToSend=JSON.stringify(toSend);

           requestNumber = JSONRequest.post(
    "http://someurl.com",
   jToSend,
    function (requestNumber, value, exception) {
        if (value) {
            processResponse(value);
            alert(value);
        } else {
            processError(exception);

        }
    }
);

   alert(requestNumber);
       }
   </script>
```

I also tried the more classic form:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var out;

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                out = xmlhttp.responseText;
                alert(out);
            }

            else alert('nothing');
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST", "the_same_url", true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        xmlhttp.send(jToSend);
```

After checking the server logs, no post is done ever :/

Answer (score 0):

You should be attaching the event to the submit action of the form and you need to make sure to cancel the submit action.

I would not add the events directly to the form, but it is

```
<form id="input" onsubmit="snifForm(); return false;">
```

Comment: and what should be added in the action="" space? Is a plain # ok since the submit action will be interrupted?

Comment: Thanks for the info; it will be something needed, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem

Comment: I used an extra function to prevent the form from submitting. This didn't work either. Now i am checking the readyState attributes to see what's wrong. As it seems, i am getting no response back and no statuses as well.

Comment: Why did you need an extra function to stop the form? Show what you did. Are you sure you are getting a 200 back?

Comment: `<script type="text/javascript"> function stopIt(){return false;}</script>` and then adding it to the onsubmit action.

Comment: I also applied the solution you proposed and the form was submitted normally :/

Comment: You probably have a JavaScript error. Set the console to keep the values on page navigation. Also what you are sending to the server appears to be wrong.

Comment: If I understood right, I have already used a control mechanism to alert me for the json string to be sent and it is in the proper form upon submission. should i check something else as well? The fact is that the ready state never changes from 1.

Comment: Update: after checking for js errors, the only one I got was concerning the initialize feature on google maps, but is totally irrelevant to the other script.

Comment: You should be posting up a name value pair to the server, you are not doing that. it should be something like "a=mystring", not "mystring". I can not debug your Ajax call from here so it is up to you to figure out why. The other portion is working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ct4eQ/

Comment: jsFiddle gave the answer! the server, even if i define that the method is POST, is still showing this error message **{"error": "Please use POST request"}**

Comment: Well the send should be posting name value pairs like I said before. `xmlhttp.send("myValues=" + encodeURIComponent(jToSend));`